# select top 10 in Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

My Access database transactions table and in that there is items, qty sold, etc

I want to do a query that select the top 10 highest items along with how many qty sold of that items till now.
How to do this? Thanks.

i am able to select the top X items but unable to select the total qty sold of that items

Comment: Search SO - lots of examples - or post a little sample data and the expected result(s).

Comment: Maybe `SELECT TOP 10 Items, Qty FROM (SELECT Items, Sum(Quantity) AS Qty FROM Transactions GROUP BY Items) ORDER BY Qty DESC;`

Comment: it contains itemid, itemname, qty , partyid   and it has many items duplicated also as it has many transactions. i want to select what top 10 items were sold for a particular party

Comment: June7th comment was the answer to the relatively general question you asked.  To further refine the question you should specify how items are duplicated and how you want to handle the duplicates then specify how a particular party is represented in your tables.  In short provide the minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks.  duplication means one customer will have purchased one item more than once. so i want to display as  - item 1 - 30 items , item 2 - 27 items, item 3 - 27 items, item 4 - 26 items, item 5 - 22 items, item 6 - 20 items, item 7 - 18 items, item 8 - 17 items, item 9 - 15 items, item 10 - 10 items